# forcing UNIQUE in mysql over two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing information about several items:

**items**
`(id (PK), name, type)`

I then have another table called 'user_and_items' which is a many to many relationship. item_id is a foreign key linked to the table above.

**users_and_items**
`(user_id (PK FK), item_id (PK FK))`

Each item has a specific type (e.g. chest piece, helmet, sword). A user should only be allowed to own one item of each type. Is there any way to enforce some sort of UNIQUE property on the `user_id` and `type` attributes in the different tables so a user cannot own two items of the same type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `type` column to `users_and_items` and make `(user_id,type)` the primary (or unique) key instead.